# Android: What are these menus and how to build them?

Tags: android, menu

I've seen this menu on the BBC News app. I was wondering If someone could help me to build menus like this.

On top of the layout, there is a menu like the image attached. How can I build something like this?

These are buttons. When I put my finger on them, the background color changes and it goes down.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

ActionBar or [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)